# Multithreading issue on linux

Tags: php, linux, multithreading, networking, centos

I have a server: Centos 6.6 \ 32 GB RAM \ 500 Mbit

**Task:**
I need to run multi thread php script that gets the content of different domains.

**Problem:**
When I increase the amount of threads from 20 to 100+, each thread works much longer and sometime I even don't get a result from remote domain. The bandwidth is also very different, comparing to 20 threads. As a result - increasing the amount on threads don't give any plus, but lowers the overall quality of the results.

**Debug:**
10 threads - 1 thread works 20 seconds
20 threads - 1 thread works 21 seconds
50 threads - 1 thread works 25 seconds
100 threads - 1 thread works 45 - 100 seconds
150 threads - 1 thread works 45 - 150 seconds

**Alternatives:**
I tried the same script on:
- Different server with Centos 7 and another php version
- On Ruby language
- On pure bash: curl + GET commands
I got totally the same!

**Question:**
What should I increase in system setting to make multi threading work correct?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You generally can't have much more threads than cores available. Assuming the application is not blocking on something you can fix, you need more parallel power. Try dumping/breaking(on the debugger)  the application when it is stuck, perhaps you will get a clue as to what thw threads are all waiting on.

Comment: I have 4 physical cores, but the problem starts with 70 - 100 threads. CPU load is almost 0, because 100 threads of curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.example.com consume nothing.

Comment: They are competing for /dev/null, in that case you would need to redirect the output to individual files (or some other non-shared resource) so they don't block each other.

Comment: I'm using separate text files for the output. When I use 50 threads with 3 seconds timeout and 50 requests per thread,  I get 100% results (2500 files) When I use 100 threads, I get 90% results, (4400 - 4600) files

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to answer without the code and the destination server you are polling, but i can assume that you are experiencing throttling by one of the many points you are going through when accessing the remote servers.
either your ISP, the remote server or your own server provider is limiting the amount of connections you can send per a second, slowing down every connection you make. this is very common in [DDOS protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS_mitigation) software.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpliest code

Thread:

```
for i in {1..50}; do
curl -s --connect-timeout 3 -o /root/tmp/${1}_${i}.txt 
http://example.com/html;
done
```

Launcher:

```
for i in {1..50}; do
nohup ./m.sh ${i} > /dev/null &
done
```